# Decision Theory and the 0-1 Loss

Tags: inference, loss-functions, decision-theory

On Page 182 of Murphy's Probabilistic ML book (http://noiselab.ucsd.edu/ECE228/Murphy_Machine_Learning.pdf) he says that to pick class 1 this should be done iff $p(\hat{y} =0 | x) > p(\hat{y} =1 | x)$ but I cannot seem to understand why this is? Could someone explain please?

Edit: Hi All,
Many Apologies as it was page 180 rather than 182.Here is the image:

[image]

I think I understand it as we only choose $y_1$ if the loss from the other choice is greater. Seeing as we don't have the option to not choose then it must be a simple choice of the case with lowest loss (i think). I would welcome those to correct my thinking

Comment: It should be the reverse

Comment: I’m with @gunes that these are reversed (if such a binary decision is even desired, which probably isn’t the case), but I’d like to see the context. I can’t imagine how the statement is true, but I’ve been surprised before.

Comment: Are you certain they're reversed?

Comment: The confusion stems from you copying the wrong notation: the earlier commenters naturally assumed $p$ represented probability, but the original (now edited in as an image) uses $\rho$, and is the expected loss.